# datatables ajax routes not working on local network

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables, routes

My problem occur in a specific case,
I'm using laravel 7, trying to make small contacts list datatable using ajax CRUD operations .
On localhost every thing is OK but when I deploy it to local network I get (404 not found ajax response)

may controller  code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
  {
      $cities = State::where("country_id",223 )->get();//223 turkey
      $countries = [];
      $countries = Country::all(); //select('name')->get()
      $datasources = [];      
      $datasources =  DB::table('contacts')->select('data_source')->distinct()->get()->toArray();
      $contact_types = [];
      $contact_types =  DB::table('contacts')->select('contact_type')->distinct()->get()->toArray();
      $data =  DB::table("contacts")
                      ->leftjoin("countries","contacts.country","=","countries.id")
                      ->leftjoin("states","contacts.city","=","states.id")
                      ->select("contacts.*", "countries.name as countryname", "states.name as statename")
                      ->latest()->get();
      if ($request->ajax()) {
          
          return Datatables::of($data)
                  ->addIndexColumn()
                  ->addColumn('action', function($row){
 
                         $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editContact">edit</a>';
 
                         $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteContact">delete</a>';
  
                          return $btn;
                  })
                  ->rawColumns(['action'])
                  ->make(true);
      }
    
      return view('contacts.contactAjax')->with([  'contacts'=>$data,
                                          'countries'=> $countries,
                                          'cities'=> $cities, 
                                          'datasources'=> $datasources, 
                                          'contact_types'=> $contact_types]); //,compact('contacts'));
  }
```

and here may whole view code:

```
@extends('contacts.layout')

    @section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1>Arabist CRM </h1>

    <a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:void(0)" id="createNewContact"> Add contact</a>
    <button  id="btn-export">EXCEL</button>
    {{--onclick="exportTableToExcel('tbl_contacts','conts.xlsx')"  <a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:exportTableToExcel('tbl_contacts','contacts.xlsx')" id="xlsx-export"> excel</a>  --}}
    <table class="table table-bordered data-table" id="tbl_contacts">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;" width="20pt">No</th>
                <th style="min-width:75pt; padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;" width="10%">name</th>
                <th style="min-width:50pt; padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;" width="10%">company</th>
                {{--  <th width="10%">birth</th>
                <th>الجنس</th>  --}}
                <th style="min-width:75pt; padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;" >email</th>
                <th style="min-width:50pt; padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;">phone</th>
                <th style="min-width:120pt; padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;" width="15%">notes</th>
                <th style="min-width:40pt; padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;">contact type</th>
              
                <th style="min-width:40pt; padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;">city</th>  
                <th style="min-width:65pt; padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;">address</th>
                <th style="min-width:80pt; padding:10pt 20pt 2pt 2pt; background-image:none;" width="8%" style="min-width:100px">control</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
   
<div class="modal fade" id="ajaxModel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modelHeading"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" class="form-horizontal">
                   <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value="" maxlength="50" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">company</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company_name" name="company_name" placeholder="Enter Name" value="" maxlength="50" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Name" value=""  >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">phone</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Name" value="" maxlength="50" required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contact_type" class="col-sm-2 control-label">type</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" list="contact_types"  name="contact_type" id="contact_type" placeholder="type" />
                            <datalist name = "contact_types" id = "contact_types" >
                                
                                    @foreach ($contact_types as $ctp)
                                        <option >{{ $ctp->contact_type }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                            </datalist>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"  style="display:none;">
                        <label for="country" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >country</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                           
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="country" id="country">
                                <option value="">--select--</option>
                                @foreach ($countries as $cnt)
                                    @if($cnt->id == 223 )
                                    <option  value="{{ $cnt->id }}" selected>{{$cnt->name}}</option>
                                    
                                    @else
                                        <option  value="{{ $cnt->id }}">{{$cnt->name}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                        <label for="city" class="col-sm-2 control-label">city</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="city" id="city">
                                <option value="">--select--</option>
                                @foreach ($cities as $cnt)
                                    @if($cnt->id == 3703 )
                                    <option  value="{{ $cnt->id }}" selected>{{$cnt->name}}</option>
                                    
                                    @else
                                        <option  value="{{ $cnt->id }}">{{$cnt->name}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter address" maxlength="50" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">notes</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <textarea id="notes" name="notes" required="" placeholder="Enter Details" class="form-control"></textarea>

                        </div>
                    </div>
      
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" id="moreDetails"  data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary  moreDetails">more details</a>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn" value="create">save 
                     </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    

    
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
     
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
    });
    function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
        var downloadLink;
        var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
        
        // Specify file name
        filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
        
        // Create download link element
        downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        
        if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
            var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
                type: dataType
            });
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
        }else{
            // Create a link to the file
            downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
        
            // Setting the file name
            downloadLink.download = filename;
            
            //triggering the function
            downloadLink.click();
        }
    }
    var table = $('#tbl_contacts').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('ajaxcontacts.index') }}",// "{{ route('ajaxcontacts.index') }}",{{ url('ajaxcontacts.index')}}
        columns: [
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'company_name', name: 'company_name'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
             {data: 'phone', name: 'phone'},
            {data: 'notes', name: 'notes'},
            {data: 'contact_type', name: 'contact_type'},
        
            {data: 'statename', name: 'city'},
            {data: 'address', name: 'address'},           
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]
    });
     $('#btn-export').click(function () {
        exportTableToExcel("tbl_contacts","fuc.xlsx");
    });
     
    $('#createNewContact').click(function () {
        $('#saveBtn').val("create-contact");
        $('#id').val('');
        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        $('#modelHeading').html("Create New Contact");
        $('#ajaxModel').modal('show');
    });
    $('body').on('click', '#moreDetails', function () {
       
      var id = $('#id').val();
      alert("id: "+ id);
      window.location.href = "contacts" +'/' + id +'/edit';//"{{ route('contacts.index') }}"
      //$.get("{{ route('contacts.index') }}" +'/' + id +'/edit')
   });
    $('body').on('click', '.editContact', function () {
       
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      //alert("id: "+ id);
      $.get( "{{ route('ajaxcontacts.index') }}" + "/" + id +"/edit", function (data) {
           //alert("data.name: " + data.name)
          $('#modelHeading').html("Edit Contact");
          $('#saveBtn').val("edit-user");
          $('#ajaxModel').modal('show');
          $('#id').val(data.id);
          $('#name').val(data.name);
          $('#company_name').val(data.company_name);
          $('#email').val(data.email);
          $('#phone').val(data.phone);
          $('#notes').val(data.notes);
          $('#contact_type').val(data.contact_type);
          $('#data_source').val(data.data_source);
          $('#country').val(data.country);
          $('#city').val(data.city);
          $('#address').val(data.address);
      })
   });
    
    $('#saveBtn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).html('Sending..');
    
        $.ajax({
          data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
          url: "{{ route('ajaxcontacts.store') }}",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
     
              $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
              $('#ajaxModel').modal('hide');
              table.draw();
         
          },
          error: function (data) {
              console.log('Error:', data);
              $('#saveBtn').html('save changes');
          }
      });
    });
    
    $('body').on('click', '.deleteContact', function () {
     
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        confirm("Are You sure want to delete !");
      
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "{{ route('ajaxcontacts.store') }}"+'/'+id,
            success: function (data) {
                table.draw();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });
     
  });
</script>
</body>
@endsection
```

and web.php routes

```
Route::resource('ajaxcontacts','ContactAjaxController')->Middleware('isAdmin');
Route::get('ajaxcontacts/index', 'ContactAjaxController@index');
```

Comment: did you check in network tab, what is the route it is calling.

Comment: yes something like Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/data=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=name&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=name&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1% ...


in localhost it's fine

Comment: please if any one has a better way to do CRUD operations (free), send me tutorial or example.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are calling a `route` from your ajax code, but you have not set up a named route within your `web.php` route file.

When you use the `route()` method, Laravel looks for a **named** route.  You call this method several times in your blade file here:

```
"{{ route('ajaxcontacts.index') }}"
```

**To Fix** just name the route in your **web.php** file:

```
Route::get('ajaxcontacts/index', 'ContactAjaxController@index')->name('ajaxcontacts.index');
```

Comment: I think it's included in
```
Route::resource('ajaxcontacts','ContactAjaxController')->Middleware('isAdmin');`
```

Comment: The resource will provide standard naming routes (`store`, `update`).  You are asking for `index` which is different.  I assume you tried the fix above and it didn't work though?

Comment: please if any one has a better way to do CRUD operations (free), send me tutorial or example.